# Recursively list directories in C on Linux

Tags: c, linux, dirent.h

I need to list all items in a directory and list all items in any sub-directories. I have this function:

```
void rls_handler(const char *name, int indent){
DIR *dir;
struct dirent *sd;
dir = opendir(name);
while((sd = readdir(dir)) != NULL){
    if(sd->d_type == DT_DIR){ //if item is a directory, print its contents
        char path[1024];
        if((strcmp(sd->d_name, ".")) !=0 &&  (strcmp(sd->d_name, "..")) != 0){ //skip '.' and '..'
            printf("%*s[%s]\n",indent,"",sd->d_name);
            rls_handler(path,indent+2); //recurse through rls_handler with subdirectory & increase indentation
    }else{
        continue;
    }    
  }else{
    printf("%*s- %s\n",indent, "", sd->d_name);
  }
}//end while
closedir(dir);
}//end rls_handler
```

I'm getting a segfault at the line: `while((sd = readdir(dir)) != NULL)`. Can anyone help me figure out why I'm getting this error?

Comment: Check what's in `dir` just before the segfault.

Comment: 'rls_handler(path,indent+2);' 'path' used uninitialized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please add a test to check that after calling :

```
dir = opendir(name);
```

dir is not null to continue working on it.

Your code should look like

```
dir = opendir(name);
if (dir!=NULL)
{
while((sd = readdir(dir)) != NULL){
...
} //end while
closedir(dir);
} // end if dir not NULL
}//end rls_handler
```